# How do I convert a list of strings to a list of dictionaries?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a list of strings that looks like this:

```
"forwarded_ports": [
    "123",
    "234",
    "456"
]
```

And I'd like to use the values of this list as values in a list of dictionaries that would look like this:

```
"mapped_ports": [
    {
        "external_port": "123",
        "internal_port": "123"
    },
    {
        "external_port": "234",
        "internal_port": "234"
    },
    {
        "external_port": "456",
        "internal_port": "456"
    }
]
```

Is there a way to do this using inline Ansible/Jinja filters?  I know I can do this easily with an Ansible loop like this:

```
- set_fact:
    mapped_ports: "{{ mapped_ports| default([]) + [{ 'internal_port' : item , 'external_port' : item }] }}"
  loop: "{{ forwarded_ports }}"
```

But ideally this data structure would be created on the fly in a defaults file with just filters, etc. It seems like there's a simple way to do it with `map` and `dict` filters but I can't seem to figure it out.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ordinarily, I don't recommend `json_query` but in this case it's a great fit for what you're trying to do because of its ability to construct new nodes via projection:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
      {{ forwarded_ports | json_query("[*].{external_port: @, internal_port: @}") }}
  vars:
    "forwarded_ports": [
      "123",
      "234",
      "456"
    ]
```

yields

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "external_port": "123",
            "internal_port": "123"
        },
        {
            "external_port": "234",
            "internal_port": "234"
        },
        {
            "external_port": "456",
            "internal_port": "456"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Again..... but this time the opposite way :D 2021-07-02 20:33:47Z against 021-07-02 20:30:52Z

Comment: Heh, I saw your answer but wanted to finish typing and also propose the more concise, albeit more opaque :-( , approach, so they could choose which they prefer

Comment: I loved `json_query`.... until I found out maintenance on jmespath side was quirky (although it looks like they are doing a better job on the last months). Meanwhile, I stopped using it unless I don't have any other choice.

Comment: Thanks for the help! As I said in my response to @Zeitounator, hopefully I'll be able to re-factor this variable out of defaults and use actual Ansible to construct it.  But if not, this will be very helpful. :-)

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell (but I don't really recommend it as it is using a var as a full jinja2 template and I would stick to your actual `set_fact` which is probably more legible for most users...):

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    forwarded_ports:
      - 123
      - 234
      - 456

    mapped_ports: >-
      {%- set mapped=[] -%}
      {%- for port in forwarded_ports -%}
        {{ mapped.append({'external_port': port, 'internal_port': port}) }}
      {%- endfor -%}
      {{ mapped }}

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: mapped_ports
```

Which gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook my_playbook.yml

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "mapped_ports": [
        {
            "external_port": 123,
            "internal_port": 123
        },
        {
            "external_port": 234,
            "internal_port": 234
        },
        {
            "external_port": 456,
            "internal_port": 456
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! So inline templating is the only way, i guess.  Yeah, I'll probably do some re-factoring to get my original solution implemented, but if that's not possible its good to know I can use this.